# difference in 0>&- and 0<&- I/O redirections

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

In example below `0>&-` works that ssh-keygen command exists when input prompt appears.
Shouldn't it be `0<&-` (close stdin) instead?
Both `0>&-` and `0<&-` seem to be working in the same way (when ssh-keygen's input/confirmation prompt appears it's closed) - how to explain it?

```
user@system:~/.ssh$ ls -al test123
ls: cannot access 'test123': No such file or directory
user@system:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f test123 -q -N "" 0>&-
user@system:~/.ssh$
user@system:~/.ssh$ ls -al test123
-rw------- 1 user user 1823 Sep 21 08:01 test123
user@system:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f test123 -q -N "" 0>&-
test123 already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? user@system:~/.ssh$
user@system:~/.ssh$
user@system:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f test123 -q -N "" 0<&-
test123 already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? user@system:~/.ssh$
```

In a [documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) there is:

```
n<&-

    Close input file descriptor n.
0<&-, <&-

    Close stdin.
n>&-

    Close output file descriptor n.
```

Comment: The construct just closes the file descriptor identified by this number. You could also use `1<&-` for closing standard output. Internally, this basically closes the [`close`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) function, and this function does not care, whether the FD is open for reading or writing or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `0>&-` and `0<&-`.

There is a difference between `>&-` and `<&-`.

That difference is:

`>&-` defaults to n=1

`<&-` defaults to n=0

See more at this [StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131801/closing-a-file-descriptor-vs#:%7E:text=You%20can%20close%20file%20descriptor,two%20syntax%20as%20the%20same.&text=If%20word%20evaluates%20to%20%27%2D%27,shall%20not%20constitute%20an%20error.)